# Italizing and inserting line break in title

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to create a line break after italicizing a word in my plot title.

The standard code is below for creating the title in ggplot2, which works:

```
labs(title = "Species\n next line", 
     y = "Y axis", 
     x = "X axis")
```

Once I customized it to italicize... the line breaks disappeared.

```
labs(title = expression (paste (italic("species"), "subspecies \n new line"))
```

How would I keep the line break that I am attempting to insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could I interest you in using `subtitle`?

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris[iris$Species == "setosa", ], aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = substitute(paste(italic("Iris"), setosa)), subtitle = "new line") +
  # labs(title = expression(italic("Iris")~"setosa"), subtitle = "new line") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  geom_point(shape = 1, size = 2)
```

[image]

To add bold font to title, you can use `bold()`.

```
ggplot(iris[iris$Species == "setosa", ], aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle(label = expression(italic("Iris")~bold("setosa")), subtitle = "new line") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "plain")) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  geom_point(shape = 1, size = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: How did you bold the italicized word?

Comment: I _think_ the appearance of bold species names comes from the fact that title uses larger size than subtitle. See my edit on how to make the font truly bold.